# problem with this reg expression

Tags: php, regex

I have a strange problem with reg expression.

I'm trying to getting out the name of the product in a string like this

```
#T55.08 #J60.91 #M1/1 #YT102/0///Tie                      #G
#T55.08 #J60.91 #M1/1 #YT102/0///Foulard                  #G
#T55.08 #J60.91 #M1/1 #YT102/0///Pocket handkerchief      #G
```

i'm using tx2re (http://txt2re.com) to create the reg expression but seems that if the product name has less then 4 character the reg exp doesn't work...
could you please help me?

this is my regex

```
/(#)(T)(55\\.08)( )(#)(J)(60\\.91)( )(#)(M)(1)(\\/1)( )(#)(YT)(102)(\\/0)(\\/)(\\/)(\\/)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))(.)((?:[a-z][a-z]+))/is
```

Comment: if the text up to the product name is always a fixed number of chars (as it appears to be in your samples), you you only need the product name, don't use a regex

Comment: that regex is a mess. what part of that string can change?

Comment: You might get more responses if you spend time doing the little things like capitalising your "I"s, and writing words out in full.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around all the unimportant/unchanging elements? You don't need them.

Comment: Are you sure you posted your regex correctly? It shouldn't be matching at all because of all those doubled backslashes...

Comment: http://txt2re.com generate this kind of regex code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This expression will capture the name of your product:

```
/#RT55\.08 #J60\.91 #M1\/1 #YT102\/0\/\/\/(.*)#G/
```

I assume that `#T55.08 #J60.91 #M1/1 #YT102/0///` and `#G` never change.

Comment: I'd replace the the `(.*)` with `(.*?)\s*` to skip the whitespace, but good otherwise.

Comment: thanks, i have many others strings like #T56.38 #J80.60 etc etc, so i need to check even the first part. so this solution is perfect!

Comment: @Matteo, just FYI, this solution only works if the first part of the string *never changes*, which is contrary to how you just commented.

Comment: I have many other strings to verify this with regex, and I need to get the name of the product only if the string begins with  #T55.08 J60.91 etc etc, if a string starts with other numbers I do not need to get the product name. thanks

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to use a regex for this problem.** If the first segment always stays the same,

```
$string = "#T55.08 #J60.91 #M1/1 #YT102/0///Pocket handkerchief      #G";
$title = trim(substr($string, 33, -2));
```

Or if it's always just after `///`:

```
$title = trim(substr($string, strpos($string,'///')+3, -2));
```

*In addition, `substr` will run much faster than a `preg_match` or `preg_replace`.*

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the string is in a given format, with a `#` at each end of a row, and fields within the row delimited by slashes.

And presumably you know that the product name will always be in the same field position in that format?

In that case, you don't really need to use a regex at all (certainly not one as horrendously complicated as the one you've come up with!). You could just chop off the leading and treailing `#` characters and explode the string by slash, and pick out the appropriate element from the resulting array:

```
$inputrow = trim($inputrow,'#');
$fields = explode('/',$inputrow);
$product_name = trim($fields[5]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If product name is always prefixed by `///` you could use:

```
preg_match('~///(.+?)\s*#G$~', $string, $matches);
```

product name will be in `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the name of the product, you can use this regex:

```
.*?\/\/\/(.*?)#G
```

However, if the initial part of your string (i.e. everything up to `///`) is fixed, you can simply use substrings.

Answer (score 0):

This really looks over complicated. If you need just the product name, you could use:

```
/\/\/\/(.*)#G$/
```