# Get digits between slashes or on the end in URL

Tags: regex, url, groovy

I need a reg expression (for groovy) to match 7 digits between 2 slashes (in a url) or on the end of the url. So fe:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032324/problem-with-this-reg-expression
```

I need 6032324 but it should also match:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032324
```

If it has 1 digit more/less, I should not match. 
Maybe its an easy reg exp but Im not so familiar with this :)

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Use `(?<=/)[0-9]{7}(?=/|$)`

Comment: small correction for groovy: str =~ /(?<=\/)\d{7}(?=\/|$)/

Comment: What if there are several such substrings in the string? Also, why not use the URL parser? Probably, `def results = new URL(surl).path.split("/").findAll { it.matches(/\d{7}/) }` will do a better job. Add `.take(1)` to get the first occurrence if you need the first occurrence only.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Glad [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50677435/3832970) worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are parsing a URL, it makes sense to use an URL parser to first grab the `path` part to split with `/`. Then, you will have direct access to the slash-separated path parts that you may test against a very simple `[0-9]{7}` pattern and get them all with

```
def results = new URL(surl).path.split("/").findAll { it.matches(/\d{7}/) }
```

You may also take the first match:

```
def results = new URL(surl).path.split("/").findAll { it.matches(/\d{7}/) }.first()
```

Or last:

```
def results = new URL(surl).path.split("/").findAll { it.matches(/\d{7}/) }.last()
```

See the [Groovy demo](https://ideone.com/WNaJuT):

```
def surl = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032324/problem-with-this-reg-expression"
def url = new URL(surl)
final result = url.path.split("/").findAll { it.matches(/\d{7}/) }.first()
print(result) // => 6032324
```